# I am having trouble with concatenation in a specific area in a variable. Where it says text=shrek + 'USD', the program keeps saying there is an error

Tags: variables, concatenation, currency, var, string-concatenation

```
settingtext = tk.Entry(window2, bg='deepskyblue', fg='blue', font='Consolas 10 bold')
settingtext2 = tk.Entry(window2, bg='deepskyblue', fg='blue', font='Consolas 10 bold')
d.create_window(125, 400, window=settingtext)
d.create_window(375, 400, window=settingtext2)
def lololol():
    d.itemconfig(fiftysix, state=NORMAL)
    d.itemconfig(line1, state=NORMAL)
    d.itemconfig(melb, state=HIDDEN)
    d.create_window(125, 200, window=settingtext)
    d.create_window(375, 200, window=settingtext2)
    d.itemconfig(text_png, state=HIDDEN)
def Settings_Page():
        d.itemconfig(fiftysix, state=HIDDEN)
        d.itemconfig(line1, state=HIDDEN)
        d.itemconfig(melb, state=NORMAL)
        d.create_window(125, 400, window=settingtext)
        d.create_window(375, 400, window=settingtext2)
        d.itemconfig(text_png, state=NORMAL)
        d.after(5000, lololol)
global zmao
global shrek
zmao = settingtext.get()
shrek = str.replace(zmao, "''", "")
zmao2 = settingtext2.get()
def Convert_Stuff():
    AUD = 1.36
    if zmao == zmao and zmao2 == zmao2: 

# over here I intend to add a string in the text part of the comma variable, but it isnt working for whatever reason.  

        comma = d.create_text(125, 450, text=shrek + 'USD', font='Aerial 20', fill='blue')
```

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: It was a concatenation error, but there was no real error message, it just showed 'USD' instead of shrek 'USD'. It kept not working, so I got pissed and ditched the project. Thanks for your corporation though.

Comment: My old messages are cringe

Comment: Not sure what programming language that was, but some don’t allow an expression as a parameter — myfunc( a = b * 4 ) — that’s why I asked what the reeor was.  Too bad you dumped it.

Comment: Lol hi, let's not worry about it now, I'm well beyond that level of programming :)